# 2d array Maze task

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am currently educating in one IT academy and I got pretty big homework, anyway, I couldn't manage to find the logic to write the code for this task, so basically I want some guides and not the entire code! :)

I have 2d array of chars which will present a maze of some sort. Lets say the array is 8x8 and I will paste an example here so you can get a better look:

```
char[][] maze = {'#','#','#',' ','#','#','#','#',},
                {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',},
                {'#',' ','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#',},
                {' ',' ',' ','$','#','#',' ',' ',},
                {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',},
                {'#',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ','#',},
                {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',},
                {'#','#','#','#','#','#',' ','#',}};
```

As you can see its mainly build by # which are walls and spaces are the 4 exits, the $ is our hero who has to escape.
So I have to write a code that asks the user, while printing this maze, to enter U,R,L,D and my $ should move accordingly, but if there is a wall it should not move. 
I've done this so far. Which is basically ask for direction and print the maze:

```
while(true) {
        System.out.println("Input direction:");
        direction = sc.next().charAt(0); 

        for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {  
            for(int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(maze[row][col] + " ")  

                }

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
```

The problem I have is that I cant really find a logic to save the position of my hero after recieving a direction. It should be something with variables and swaping elements of the array but I am struggling all day, so I decided to ask here. If I find how to do this I am pretty sure I know how to do the rest! :)

NB! I am at a point at my education that I can use only loops, conditions and arrays basically :) So any help is welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: The loops uses `row` and `col` when displaying the maze.  A natural extension might be to have `heroCurrentRow` and `heroCurrentCol`.  Those would need to be defined and initialized above the while loop, and updated if `direction` is valid.

Comment: To add to @AndrewS's comment (which is a good one): You'll need to track the hero's location and then check the new location against the 2d array to ensure they aren't running into a wall or off the maze. If it's a valid location to move to, then redraw the array elements checking each element to see if it matches the hero's new location, then draw your '$' there.

Comment: Thanks! Thought it should be something like this I will work some more but this directions were very useful! Thank u guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a variable for the heroX and hero Y location, loop through the entire 2d array once if you have to. After you have that, you should check if the location they are trying to move in is a wall or exit. 'U' would be location `maze[heroY-1][heroX]`, 'D' would be location `maze[heroY+1][heroX]`, etc. When a location is entered, you want to update the heroX, heroY, and the maze variables.

EDIT: forgot vertical value goes first in 2d array

Comment: Thanks! :) Very useful as well! :)

Comment: No problem, and instead of checking for hero location while printing the array like recommended in comment above, I would just update the 2d array first and then just print it. This is more efficient. Make old location a space and new location a dollar sign (after checking if possible to move ofc)

Comment: Yeah my thoughts as well I would probably do it like this anyway, still thanks again for the help! I lost 4 hours trying to figure it out today :D